# What is the current method of debugging Windows Outlook for Desktop Add-in?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook add-in for the Outlook Windows Desktop App using React, in a project generated with Yeoman. While I am able develop and sideload my add-in, I am unable to debug it or get any `console.log` statements to print.

To develop, I run `node --inspect ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js serve --mode development`, which starts the webpack server on `https://localhost:3000`, while the inspect server runs on `wss://localhost:9226`.

On `localhost:3000`, I am able to access `localhost:3000` as a webpage and inspect whatever logs I put in React. On `localhost:9226`, I am able to inspect the webpack build process and compilation time.

In Outlook, I am able to modify my React files and have the task-pane change accordingly.

---

However, what I need to be able to do is inspect the log when using the `Office` API exposed to Outlook add-ins, so I can debug when I'm clicking into emails or generating other events.

I have downloaded **Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview** but neither `localhost` shows up in **Local**, and trying to navigate to either `localhost` ports under **Remote** fails.

I have also downloaded the VSCode Extension **Microsoft Office Add In Debugger**, even though it is deprecated; following the instructions there, I was able to start a Node debugger, but the only thing it returns is **Edge Instances: []**.
For reference, the `launch.json` config I'm using is:

```
{
      "type": "office-addin",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Office Add-ins",
      "port": 9222,
      "trace": "verbose",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "timeout": 45000
}
```

---

I also generated a fresh instance using Yeoman and copied the relevant 'launch.json' contents over

```
{
      "name": "Outlook Desktop (Edge Legacy)",
      "type": "office-addin",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "port": 9222,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Outlook Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
},
{
      "name": "Outlook Desktop (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "msedge",
      "request": "attach",
      "useWebView": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 6000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Outlook Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
}
```

Running either option leads to the error: '**Could not find Debug: Outlook Desktop**'. Deleting that line from both option leads to 2 different results.

Running **Outlook Desktop (Edge Legacy)** has the same result as following the steps for **Microsoft Office Add In Debugger**, which is just a node debugger that only returns **Edge Instances: []**.

Running **Outlook Desktop (Edge Chromium)** leads to another error:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but after sideloading the add-in on the Outlook App, it's possible to use F12 Dev Tools in Chrome to debug the add-in on the Outlook Web App.

Comment: If this is a webview add-in, you can open the MS Edge dev console from the traskpane that the add-in was opened in. If this is an event-based add-in, you can follow these instructions to debug your add-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch?tabs=windows